# Looking for an API or easily readable format for land cover data

Tags: netcdf, land-cover

I'm working on a web application to take a look at the entire globe with a sim-city like experience.

To build the world, I need access to land-cover data. One I've found is the [CCI Landcover data](http://maps.elie.ucl.ac.be/CCI/viewer/index.php). Their downloads are in the NetCDF format.

The challenge I've been having is that my language of choice doesnt have libraries to deal with this format that A) work, B) allow random access and C) don't put the entire file in memory. So to turn this into the file I need, I've not been able to do this without OOM issues.

I'm curious if anyone here is aware of APIs that are easier to use with, or alternative approaches to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert the file file to GeoTIFF and use https://geotiffjs.github.io/ to parse the file, fast!

This is how I converted my file:

```
gdalwarp -of Gtiff -co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES -ot Byte -te -180.0000000 -90.0000000 180.0000000 90.0000000 -tr 0.002777777777778 0.002777777777778 -t_srs EPSG:4326 NETCDF:C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2020-v2.1.1.nc:lccs_class world.tif
```